# Why does my event property code cause a stack overflow exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, properties, user-controls

I'm making a custom button (Winforms Control Library) and have the code below so that all mouseenter will be added to all controls in my button. When I run it, it causes a stack overflow exception. I have the same code with Click instead of MouseEnter and it works fine. Here is the code:

```
public new event EventHandler MouseEnter {
    add
    {
        this.MouseEnter += value;
        foreach (Control i in Controls)
        {
            i.MouseEnter += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        this.MouseEnter -= value;
        foreach (Control i in Controls)
        {
            i.MouseEnter -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the click code:

```
public new event EventHandler Click {
    add {
        this.Click += value;
        foreach (Control i in Controls) {
            i.Click += value;
        }
    }
    remove {
        this.Click -= value;
        foreach (Control i in Controls) {
            i.Click -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replaceing this.Click with base.Click.

```
    public new event EventHandler Click {
        add {
            base.Click += value;
            foreach (Control i in Controls) {
                i.Click += value;
            }
        }
        remove {
            base.Click -= value;
            foreach (Control i in Controls) {
                i.Click -= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works if you only ever raise the base version of `Click`; your version of `Click` has become nothing but a *helper method to propagate the subscription of a handler to the control's children.* **Please don't hide this logic behind an event adder, just make a clearly named and commented helper method.**

Answer (score 5):

`+=` is shorthand for "invoke the adder for this event." You are calling `+=` from your adder. Thus you have unbound recursion, leading to the stack overflow.

Looking at your code, it appears that you are defining the adder yourself in order to add and remove the handler not only from the control, but from all its children as well. This strikes me as a pretty bad idea: subscribers to a given event have the reasonable expectation that they will only be notified when the actual event is fired, and not whenever the event is fired by any number of publishers about which they know nothing.

If you want to create helper methods that do this, that would probably make more sense, since now consumers invoking the methods know exactly what they're getting into. As well, that would get rid of your recursion bug to boot.

Finally, this functionality is probably unnecessary: many events will bubble up from children to parents anyway.

Comment: i know but why does my click code work, its the same except MouseEnter is replaced with Click, when this one doesnt?

Comment: Yup the code this.MouseEnter += value;
causes another eventhandler to be added to MouseEnter. The reason you get the stack overflow quicker than on click is that for every movement of the mouse this code gets called

Comment: @leaf68 Could you paste the code for the `Click` event? That's pretty strange.

Comment: @leaf68 That's very weird. No real idea why one would work and the other wouldn't, and probably can't without seeing even *more* code. Maybe try stepping through the `Click` adder with a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: ok nevermind, both do not work. i added a new event to Click and it had the same exception

Comment: @leaf68 Less weird :) I do think you should consider my suggestion of having a standard event with a helper method. I think it would be a lot cleaner. Also, I suspect that you're hiding the base class versions of the events in order to get this special processing working. Without it, I assume you could drop the event definition entirely.

Comment: @dlev i figured it out, see my answer. I replaced this.Click with base.Click

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted something like this (not sure if its right for the private member):

```
private EventHandler mouseEnter;
public new event EventHandler MouseEnter {
add
{
    this.mouseEnter += value;
    foreach (Control i in Controls)
    {
        i.mouseEnter += value;
    }
}
remove
{
    this.mouseEnter -= value;
    foreach (Control i in Controls)
    {
        i.mouseEnter -= value;
    }
}
```

}

You have `this.MouseEnter` calling itself in recursion.